# Python Swig interface for C function allocating a list of structures

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, list, swig

I'm trying to get the following C function to be exposed as a python interface.

```
void myfunc(struct MyStruct** list, int* size) {
    int n = 10;
    *size = n;
    *list = (struct MyStruct*) malloc(n * sizeof(struct MyStruct));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        (*list)[i].x = i;
        (*list)[i].y = i * 0.1;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the swig documentation didn't help narrow down on a solution. Could you please help with any pointers or code references to how we can write a corresponding swig interface file to make this function be called from python?

It would be a bonus if I could access this as a list of objects in python.

Comment: did you read [12.2 C arrays and pointers](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_nn3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it (error checking left out):

**SWIG Interface File - test.i**

```c
%module test

%{ // code to include directly in the wrapper
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    double y;
};

void myfunc(struct MyStruct** list, int* size) {
    int n = 10;
    *size = n;
    *list = (struct MyStruct*) malloc(n * sizeof(struct MyStruct));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        (*list)[i].x = i;
        (*list)[i].y = i * 0.1;
    }
}
%}

// On input, do not require the list/size parameters.
// Instead, declare tmp variables and pass them by reference
// to capture the output arguments.
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) (struct MyStruct** list, int* size) (struct MyStruct* tmp, int size) %{
    $1 = &tmp;
    $2 = &size;
%}

// After the function call, append the returned pointer and size to the output result.
%typemap(argout) (struct MyStruct** list, int* size) %{
    PyObject* obj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(*$1, $descriptor(struct MyStruct*), 0);
    PyObject* s = PyLong_FromLong(*$2);
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, obj);
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, s);
%}

// Use the pre-defined SWIG typemaps to handle C pointers and arrays.
%include <carrays.i>
%include <cpointer.i>
%pointer_functions(struct MyStruct, pMyStruct);
%array_functions(struct MyStruct, MyStructArray);

// Make Python wrappers for the below struct and function.
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    double y;
};

void myfunc(struct MyStruct** list, int* size);
```

**Python test file - example.py**

```py
import test

# Helper function to put all the returned data in a list
# and manage the allocated pointer.
def myfunc():
    ptr, size = test.myfunc()
    try:
        arr = []
        objs = [test.MyStructArray_getitem(ptr, i) for i in range(size)]
        return [(obj.x, obj.y) for obj in objs]
    finally:
        test.delete_pMyStruct(ptr)

print(myfunc())
```

Output:

```py
[(0, 0.0), (1, 0.1), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.30000000000000004), (4, 0.4), (5, 0.5), (6, 0.6000000000000001), (7, 0.7000000000000001), (8, 0.8), (9, 0.9)]
```

---

If you want to completely handle the data conversion in the SWIG wrapper, here's an example:

**test.i**

```c
%module test

%{ // code to include directly in the wrapper
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    double y;
};

void myfunc(struct MyStruct** list, int* size) {
    int n = 10;
    *size = n;
    *list = (struct MyStruct*) malloc(n * sizeof(struct MyStruct));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        (*list)[i].x = i;
        (*list)[i].y = i * 0.1;
    }
}
%}

// On input, do not require the list/size parameters.
// Instead, declare tmp variables and pass them by reference
// to capture the output arguments.
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) (struct MyStruct** list, int* size) (struct MyStruct* tmp, int size) %{
    $1 = &tmp;
    $2 = &size;
%}

// After the function call, Build a list of tuples with the x/y data from the structs.
%typemap(argout) (struct MyStruct** list, int* size) (PyObject* list) %{
    list = PyList_New(*$2);
    for(int i = 0; i < *$2; ++i) {
        PyObject* t = PyTuple_New(2);
        PyTuple_SET_ITEM(t, 0, PyLong_FromLong((*$1)[i].x));
        PyTuple_SET_ITEM(t, 1, PyFloat_FromDouble((*$1)[i].y));
        PyList_SET_ITEM(list, i, t);
    }
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, list);
%}

// Free the allocated structure array
%typemap(freearg) (struct MyStruct** list, int* size) %{
    free(*$1);
%}

// Make Python wrappers for the below struct and function.
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    double y;
};

void myfunc(struct MyStruct** list, int* size);
```

**example.py**

```py
import test
print(test.myfunc())
```

Output:

```py
[(0, 0.0), (1, 0.1), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.30000000000000004), (4, 0.4), (5, 0.5), (6, 0.6000000000000001), (7, 0.7000000000000001), (8, 0.8), (9, 0.9)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mark! This gives me some pointers in the documentation as well. I didn't realize we could create pointer to pointer using *$1. 

I had 2 follow ups: 
== would the above technique would work for structures with non-primitive member variables, eg:  array of int or struct
== Would we able to deep copy the memory to a new object during the typemap(argout) and free the memory allocated in the function, so that the caller does not have to be burdened with the memory management.

Comment: Note `*$1` is dereferencing the `MyStruct**` to get the `MyStruct*`.  And yes,  you could directly construct a Python list containing the data returned in the objects in the `%typemap(argout)` then deallocate the memory with a `%typemap(freearg)`.

Comment: I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Also you *can* have array of int or struct in the structures, but it gets more complicated of course.

Comment: Hi Mark, following up on the following statement you mentioned: "construct a Python list containing the data returned in the objects" , does this mean a list containing SWIG_NewPointerObj of each C structure variable, saved as opaque PyObject?

Comment: @Maverickgugu No it refers to my added example where it constructed a tuple of the structure data, but you could do it the way you stated as well

Comment: would it be some thing like this where i is the position in the array:
PyObject\* t = SWIG_NewPointerObj(&((\*$1)[i]), $descriptor(struct MyStruct*), 0);

Comment: Looks right, but now you won’t be able to use the freearg typemap and the memory will leak. Copying to a tuple solved that. Better off using my first implementation where you can still decide when to free the array

Comment: I am contemplating experimenting a custom destructor function for the structure. Do you feel that is path worth exploring considering  in this context?

Comment: @Maverickgugu Not for the second solution. The array is created with a single malloc, but turning it into a Python list of pointers to individual elements they wouldn’t know when to deallocate the array.  You could with the first solution and could also write custom `__repr__` to make it *look* like a Python list.

Comment: I got a working solution using a modified version of your second approach. I'll add it an answer as I'm not able to add markups to comments. 
I'm not sure if there would be leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top Mark's second approach. I came up with the following interface file. I'm not sure if there would be leaks, just adding it here to seek comments.

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}

// On input, do not require the list/size parameters.
// Instead, declare tmp variables and pass them by reference
// to capture the output arguments.
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) (struct MyStruct** list, int* size) (struct MyStruct* tmp, int size) %{
    $1 = &tmp;
    $2 = &size;
%}

// After the function call, Build a list of objects from the structs.
%typemap(argout) (struct MyStruct** list, int* size) (PyObject* list) %{
    list = PyList_New(*$2);
    for(int i = 0; i < *$2; ++i) {
        struct MyStruct* t = (struct MyStruct*)malloc(sizeof((*$1)[i]));
        t->x = (*$1)[i].x;
        t->y = (*$1)[i].y;
        PyObject* t1 = SWIG_NewPointerObj(t, SWIGTYPE_p_MyStruct, SWIG_POINTER_OWN);
        PyList_SET_ITEM(list, i, (PyObject*)t1);
    }
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, list);
%}

// Free the allocated structure array
%typemap(freearg) (struct MyStruct** list, int* size) %{
    free(*$1);
%}

%include "example.h"
```

Now the objects could be accessed more organically? Unsure about the memory handling part in this case.

```
>>> import example as e
>>> a = e.myfunc()
0xbf2b30 
>>> al = [(b.x,b.y) for b in a]
>>> al
[(0, 0.0), (1, 0.10000000149011612), (2, 0.20000000298023224), (3, 0.30000001192092896), (4, 0.4000000059604645), (5, 0.5), (6, 0.6000000238418579), (7, 0.699999988079071), (8, 0.800000011920929), (9, 0.8999999761581421)]
```